# Projects/Package Naming Convention?

Tags: java, c++, project

I just know only naming convention of variable, constant, method... but I don't know naming convention of project and package. Anybody can help me ? Addition, name of project should have white space ? Thanks very much !

Comment: What technology are you using?

Answer (score 26):

In Java, package names are lowercase, no spaces. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

You probably don't have to be so fussy with the project names. My recommendation is PascalCase, although I've seen some [like this one](http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/plugin_help/java_project.html) that are camelCase (which I find odd). Sun [just uses capitalized phrases](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/codenames-136090.html) for their project names.

Comment: Just wondering, is java.about.com good reference? I'd expect something like xyz.oracle.com nowadays, for example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html (but there is nothing about package naming conventions), in this tutorial it's defined properly - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html (of course your answer is quite old, so those documents probably didn't exist before)

Comment: Project names could be a part of URL for requests. In this case hyphen separator is recommended by SEO. Isn't it?

Comment: @Zon: I doubt it.  That advice is probably outdated.

Comment: You can find an example in the URL of this page.

Comment: @zon: Well, sure.  But the presence of hyphens isn't necessarily an endorsement for SEO technique.  You're confusing correlation with causation.